# How to focus on textarea based on click?

Tags: jquery, focus, textarea

I have some code that when a user clicks on a link "Add Comment", it looks a certain named div next to it and slidetoggles down that div. Inside of that div I have a textarea.

My goal is to set the focus on the textarea when the user clicks the "Add Comment" link.
The problem I'm running into is I will have multiple comments/textareas/add comment links and I need it so when you click on "Add Comment" it focuses on the corresponding textarea.

Heres what I have so far:

jQuery

```
$(".add-comment-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".inline-comment-form").slideToggle(200);
    $(this).next(".inline-comment-form textarea").focus();
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="add-comment-btn" href="#">Add Comment</a>         

<div class="inline-comment-form">
<form action="" method="post">
        <div class="textarea">
            <textarea class="inline-comment-textarea" name="comment-textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input value="SUBMIT" name="submit-inline-comment" class="form-btn" type="submit">

    </form>
</div><!--/Inline Comment Form -->
```

**Edit:** I updated the code to add the Add Comment link and moved the return false

Comment: could you post a larger junk of HTML that includes the add comment? I wanna give you a jsbin link with a demo, but I want to make sure the HTML is the same :)

Comment: Do you mean to have the return false before the focus call?  This, of course, won't work.

Comment: Yeah, thats true hybrid, if you can move the return false to the very end do it. If not, try changing your <a> to a <span> or something and just style it

Comment: @Oscar - Sorry I think that top bit of code got clipped the first time.

@John - Thanks for that info. I wasn't aware of that. So if I use return false; it should go at the very end?

Comment: Yes, return false is basically like a break; or kill; in other langs. It'll stop there and jump out of the current scope (correct me if im wrong other peoples on the StackOverflows)

Comment: If moving return false STILL doesnt fix it, ill give you a JSBin demo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Frgxv/

```
$(".add-comment-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".inline-comment-form").slideToggle(200)
           .find("textarea").focus();

    return false;
});
```

`next` only works with siblings, the textarea isn't a sibling.

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I was looking for. I vaguely remember that quality about next, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/XNkES/

I am using the following code that seems to work:

```
$(this).next(".inline-comment-form").slideToggle(200).find('textarea').focus();
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks jackrugile